How i create complete regression line on nominal type x axis in Vegalite
I am trying to create a regression in vegalite , my data has nominal type field on x axis and quantitative type field on y axis but regression line is not showing .
If i use  { "window": [ { "as": "rank", "op": "row_number" } ] }
in transform and make use rank in regression layer then regression line i completely not form refernce not regression line on whole data 
i want to show label on x axis in same as Period ("Period": "01-Jan-21-31-Jan-21")
How i can create complete visible regression line on large dataset of x axis nominal field.
Can any how i can use temporal type on axis axis as well show same label as Period in my data on x axis.
Editor link
Extra useful link Regression line on temporal type
